# importing cv2 in python3.7.5 outputs something unusual

Tags: python-3.x, import, output, opencv, python

I have been trying to run a **python3** file which imports **cv2** latest version 4.4 but when i run the file it is printing something unusual even though I do not have any print command

```
import cv2
```

It justs prints **8** blocks from 0-7 with some **colors** and numbers on it. But when run in **python2** its works fine

Output (without **colors**):

0;30;40  0;30;41  0;30;42  0;30;43  0;30;44  0;30;45  0;30;46  0;30;47
0;31;40  0;31;41  0;31;42  0;31;43  0;31;44  0;31;45  0;31;46  0;31;47
0;32;40  0;32;41  0;32;42  0;32;43  0;32;44  0;32;45  0;32;46  0;32;47
0;33;40  0;33;41  0;33;42  0;33;43  0;33;44  0;33;45  0;33;46  0;33;47
0;34;40  0;34;41  0;34;42  0;34;43  0;34;44  0;34;45  0;34;46  0;34;47
0;35;40  0;35;41  0;35;42  0;35;43  0;35;44  0;35;45  0;35;46  0;35;47
0;36;40  0;36;41  0;36;42  0;36;43  0;36;44  0;36;45  0;36;46  0;36;47
0;37;40  0;37;41  0;37;42  0;37;43  0;37;44  0;37;45  0;37;46  0;37;47

1;30;40  1;30;41  1;30;42  1;30;43  1;30;44  1;30;45  1;30;46  1;30;47
1;31;40  1;31;41  1;31;42  1;31;43  1;31;44  1;31;45  1;31;46  1;31;47
1;32;40  1;32;41  1;32;42  1;32;43  1;32;44  1;32;45  1;32;46  1;32;47
1;33;40  1;33;41  1;33;42  1;33;43  1;33;44  1;33;45  1;33;46  1;33;47
1;34;40  1;34;41  1;34;42  1;34;43  1;34;44  1;34;45  1;34;46  1;34;47
1;35;40  1;35;41  1;35;42  1;35;43  1;35;44  1;35;45  1;35;46  1;35;47
1;36;40  1;36;41  1;36;42  1;36;43  1;36;44  1;36;45  1;36;46  1;36;47
1;37;40  1;37;41  1;37;42  1;37;43  1;37;44  1;37;45  1;37;46  1;37;47

2;30;40  2;30;41  2;30;42  2;30;43  2;30;44  2;30;45  2;30;46  2;30;47
2;31;40  2;31;41  2;31;42  2;31;43  2;31;44  2;31;45  2;31;46  2;31;47
2;32;40  2;32;41  2;32;42  2;32;43  2;32;44  2;32;45  2;32;46  2;32;47
2;33;40  2;33;41  2;33;42  2;33;43  2;33;44  2;33;45  2;33;46  2;33;47
2;34;40  2;34;41  2;34;42  2;34;43  2;34;44  2;34;45  2;34;46  2;34;47
2;35;40  2;35;41  2;35;42  2;35;43  2;35;44  2;35;45  2;35;46  2;35;47
2;36;40  2;36;41  2;36;42  2;36;43  2;36;44  2;36;45  2;36;46  2;36;47
2;37;40  2;37;41  2;37;42  2;37;43  2;37;44  2;37;45  2;37;46  2;37;47

3;30;40  3;30;41  3;30;42  3;30;43  3;30;44  3;30;45  3;30;46  3;30;47
3;31;40  3;31;41  3;31;42  3;31;43  3;31;44  3;31;45  3;31;46  3;31;47
3;32;40  3;32;41  3;32;42  3;32;43  3;32;44  3;32;45  3;32;46  3;32;47
3;33;40  3;33;41  3;33;42  3;33;43  3;33;44  3;33;45  3;33;46  3;33;47
3;34;40  3;34;41  3;34;42  3;34;43  3;34;44  3;34;45  3;34;46  3;34;47
3;35;40  3;35;41  3;35;42  3;35;43  3;35;44  3;35;45  3;35;46  3;35;47
3;36;40  3;36;41  3;36;42  3;36;43  3;36;44  3;36;45  3;36;46  3;36;47
3;37;40  3;37;41  3;37;42  3;37;43  3;37;44  3;37;45  3;37;46  3;37;47

4;30;40  4;30;41  4;30;42  4;30;43  4;30;44  4;30;45  4;30;46  4;30;47
4;31;40  4;31;41  4;31;42  4;31;43  4;31;44  4;31;45  4;31;46  4;31;47
4;32;40  4;32;41  4;32;42  4;32;43  4;32;44  4;32;45  4;32;46  4;32;47
4;33;40  4;33;41  4;33;42  4;33;43  4;33;44  4;33;45  4;33;46  4;33;47
4;34;40  4;34;41  4;34;42  4;34;43  4;34;44  4;34;45  4;34;46  4;34;47
4;35;40  4;35;41  4;35;42  4;35;43  4;35;44  4;35;45  4;35;46  4;35;47
4;36;40  4;36;41  4;36;42  4;36;43  4;36;44  4;36;45  4;36;46  4;36;47
4;37;40  4;37;41  4;37;42  4;37;43  4;37;44  4;37;45  4;37;46  4;37;47

5;30;40  5;30;41  5;30;42  5;30;43  5;30;44  5;30;45  5;30;46  5;30;47
5;31;40  5;31;41  5;31;42  5;31;43  5;31;44  5;31;45  5;31;46  5;31;47
5;32;40  5;32;41  5;32;42  5;32;43  5;32;44  5;32;45  5;32;46  5;32;47
5;33;40  5;33;41  5;33;42  5;33;43  5;33;44  5;33;45  5;33;46  5;33;47
5;34;40  5;34;41  5;34;42  5;34;43  5;34;44  5;34;45  5;34;46  5;34;47
5;35;40  5;35;41  5;35;42  5;35;43  5;35;44  5;35;45  5;35;46  5;35;47
5;36;40  5;36;41  5;36;42  5;36;43  5;36;44  5;36;45  5;36;46  5;36;47
5;37;40  5;37;41  5;37;42  5;37;43  5;37;44  5;37;45  5;37;46  5;37;47

6;30;40  6;30;41  6;30;42  6;30;43  6;30;44  6;30;45  6;30;46  6;30;47
6;31;40  6;31;41  6;31;42  6;31;43  6;31;44  6;31;45  6;31;46  6;31;47
6;32;40  6;32;41  6;32;42  6;32;43  6;32;44  6;32;45  6;32;46  6;32;47
6;33;40  6;33;41  6;33;42  6;33;43  6;33;44  6;33;45  6;33;46  6;33;47
6;34;40  6;34;41  6;34;42  6;34;43  6;34;44  6;34;45  6;34;46  6;34;47
6;35;40  6;35;41  6;35;42  6;35;43  6;35;44  6;35;45  6;35;46  6;35;47
6;36;40  6;36;41  6;36;42  6;36;43  6;36;44  6;36;45  6;36;46  6;36;47
6;37;40  6;37;41  6;37;42  6;37;43  6;37;44  6;37;45  6;37;46  6;37;47

7;30;40  7;30;41  7;30;42  7;30;43  7;30;44  7;30;45  7;30;46  7;30;47
7;31;40  7;31;41  7;31;42  7;31;43  7;31;44  7;31;45  7;31;46  7;31;47
7;32;40  7;32;41  7;32;42  7;32;43  7;32;44  7;32;45  7;32;46  7;32;47
7;33;40  7;33;41  7;33;42  7;33;43  7;33;44  7;33;45  7;33;46  7;33;47
7;34;40  7;34;41  7;34;42  7;34;43  7;34;44  7;34;45  7;34;46  7;34;47
7;35;40  7;35;41  7;35;42  7;35;43  7;35;44  7;35;45  7;35;46  7;35;47
7;36;40  7;36;41  7;36;42  7;36;43  7;36;44  7;36;45  7;36;46  7;36;47
7;37;40  7;37;41  7;37;42  7;37;43  7;37;44  7;37;45  7;37;46  7;37;47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to whosoever tried to solve this. I resolved the issue. The problem was in the local directory where the **init**.py file of cv2 was kept. It was printing some weird code which I commented out and worked properly.